# Material-UI text field with the multiline prop is not working with a variant prop of value outlined

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, textfield

**I am trying to use the material-UI text field as a text area with a multiline prop but its height is not getting bigger according to rows prop, although if I remove a prop variant=" outlined" it gets to start to work just not with the outlined boundary although I try the same props in code sandbox and it works perfectly fine but not here, please point out what I am not doing right?**

```
import { withStyles, Grid, TextField } from '@material-ui/core';
const textFieldStyle = {
  background: '#ffff',
  borderRadius: 5,
  width: '100%',
};
const StyledTextArea = withStyles({
  root: {
    '& .MuiOutlinedInput-root > .MuiInputBase-input': {
      fontSize: 13,
    },
  },
})(TextField);
export default function Template(props) {
  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <Grid container>
        <Grid item xs={7}>
          <StyledTextArea
            id="outlined-multiline-static"
            label="Multiline"
            multiline
            rows={4}
            defaultValue="Default Value"
            variant="outlined"
            style={{ ...textFieldStyle }}
          />
        </Grid>
      </Grid>
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try add a `paddingHorizontal` to the textInput text. This will make the width expand as the text input gets filled out. You can also add a maximum preferred with using `maxWidth`

```
So under style try this:


<StyledTextArea
        id="outlined-multiline-static"
        label="Multiline"
        multiline
        rows={4}
        defaultValue="Default Value"
        variant="outlined"
        style={[{ ...textFieldStyle },{paddingHorizontal:20, maxWidth:100}]}
  />
```

Comment: I just tried but didn't work. I even make sure that its outer container must have maximum height so its height can increase by increasing rows prop value but not working

Comment: Let me make one correction the issue is with height by increasing rows prop value it should increase